# How to pass dynamic link to jwPlayer in mvc 5 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am working on website using `MVC 5` website is actually a video website which is suppose to load CDNSun storage videos....
How can i pass the dynamic link using "videoUrl" parameter..???
code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        'file': 'rtmp://872083564.r.cdnsun.net/872083564/_definst_/
                   mp4:872083564/(here i want to put videoUrl).mp4',
        'title': 'Title',
        'description': 'Description',
        'controlbar': 'bottom'
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EpisodeList(Guid? id)
{
    IQueryable<VideoEpisodeDM> episodesdm = db.VideoEpisode
        .Where(ve => ve.VideoId == id);

    string video;

    foreach (var item in episodesdm)
    {
        video = item.Title;
        ViewBag.VideoUrl = item.VideoUrl;
    }


    return View(episodesdm.ToList());
}
```

**Any help or help reference will be appreciated...thanks for your time in advance**

Comment: its actually an action of controller, and looking for jquery function to pass value or simply any other method to pass dynamic link such as @Model.videoUrl

Comment: Have you tried   mp4:872083564/V@iewBag.VideoUrl .mp4',?

Comment: yes i'have tried but it didn't work...some reference files needed for that method??? i mean multi-part type code??

Comment: See my answer to solve the multi type code issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of two approaches:

1. create the value in a tmp javascript variable

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var tmpVideo = "@iewBag.VideoUrl";
           tmpVideo = "872083564/" + tmpVideo + ".mp4";
           jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
               'file': 'rtmp://872083564.r.cdnsun.net/872083564/_definst_/
                      mp4:tmpVideo,
               'title': 'Title',
               'description': 'Description',
               'controlbar': 'bottom'
           });
       });
   ```

Or just use curly brackets around your Razor code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
            'file': 'rtmp://872083564.r.cdnsun.net/872083564/_definst_/
                       mp4:872083564/@{ViewBag.VideoUrl}.mp4',
            'title': 'Title',
            'description': 'Description',
            'controlbar': 'bottom'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@ViewBag.VideoUrl` in file and `.mp4` should be in videoUrl. 
Works fine for me, and dont forget to use `securetoken` for security :-)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
            'file': 'rtmp://872083564.r.cdnsun.net/872083564/_definst_/
                       mp4:872083564/@ViewBag.VideoUrl',
            'title': 'Title',
            'description': 'Description',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
    rtmp: {
                    securetoken: "some generated key"
                },
        });
    });
```

Comment: try to find the key at cdnsun account settings